# Count how many times a ComboBox item was selected in C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, tcombobox

I need your help to resolve my problem.

I have a ComboBox with 2 items: `StackExchange`, and `StackOverflow`.

I want to know how to count of how many times `StackOverflow` item was selected and put the results in a messagebox.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of two `int` values, initialized to 0s.  In the [`TComboBox::OnSelect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomCombo.OnSelect) event, increment the appropriate array item based on the index reported by the [`TComboBox::ItemIndex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TCustomListControl.ItemIndex) property.

```
private:
    int Counters[2];

void __fastcall TMyForm::ComboBox1Select(TOBJECT *Sender)
{
    Counters[ComboBox1->ItemIndex]++;
}

void __fastcall TMyForm::DisplayCounts()
{
    String Msg;
    Msg.sprintf(_D("%s: %d\n%s: %d"),
        ComboBox1->Items->Strings[0].c_str(), Counters[0],
        ComboBox1->Items->Strings[1].c_str(), Counters[1]
    );
    ShowMessage(Msg);
}
```

Comment: All the praises and thanks be to the God!. Like your answers beforehand, this answer is also works perfectly. You're so great, indeed. Thank you very...really much, Remy!.